# What is the toothed side of the blade on a Fantastique veg cutter used for?

Tags: cutting, cutting-boards

In India I picked up an Anjali vegetable and fruit cutting board, pictured below.  Its blade is two-sided: straight on one end, very roughly serrated on the other.

What is the toothed side used for?  [In this demonstration video from the manufacturer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o52OT32bj1g) they never show it being used.  It does show a pineapple with some fancy decoration, so if this happens to be the use, please explain precisely how to achieve that.

[image: vegetable and fruit cutting board]

Comment: Off topic: Saw the video. For me the whole contraption looks like an excellent away to get rid of some excess fingers.

Comment: Only a guess -- you might be able to use that side to tenderize meat like what's sold as 'cube steak' in the US, but it might take considerable effort, as the blade can't move, and you'd have to keep moving the meat.  And that's not likely their intention, as it's called a 'vegetable and fruit' cutting board.

Comment: Do you have a higher resolution image?

Comment: @Mołot I've added a better image.

Comment: Well, I could give an answer that proffers some conjecture on how that side is _not_ like a saw, nor meant to cut anything in any similar manner.  If you wouldn't mind guesswork and supposition, that is.

Comment: @can-ned_food No thanks, I've seen many conjectures already.  So far the most compelling idea is it could act as a coconut scraper: http://www.jdproductsindia.co.in/coconut-scraper.html  I'm looking for someone who has actually seen this toothed blade used in practice.

Comment: Isn't it just for chopping shapes? Like cubed melon/pineapple/cucumber etc?

Comment: The video has gone offline.  Have another link?

Answer (score 1):

Either for rough chops on veg/herbs, or maybe decorating with icing/chocolate design?

Regardless, this seems like a poorly thought out tool?

Comment: Can you please explain exactly how I should to use this to roughly chop veg/herbs?  Also is this a guess or have you seen it done?